# Error while installing the DXA2.2 TBBs in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5

I am trying to import the DXA 2.2 TBBs to Tridion Web 8.5 using `cms-import.ps1` command which is returning the Core Service related error shown below:

> Screenshot of error[image]

[image]

In Tridion Web 8.5, we have Core Service 2016 but the script is trying to find the 2017 version. Are there any changes in the script or configuration to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Velmurugan for the help
So It was trying to install the TBB in the publication which doesn't exist
There should be some parameter to pass the publication name, so I renamed my site in CMS  to 110 DXA Site Type and it started working fine.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK In the DXA 2.2+ the **cms-import.ps1** has CoreService Contract Version check logic and automatically determines the correct version to pick up the correct import packages.

It doesn't need any configuration changes. not sure you are using the correct version of **cms-import.ps1** install script from DXA 2.2+, or could be something that goes wrong in this below script version check.

Here is the code reference which is used in the cms-import.ps1 script for the version check:

```
function Is-Sites9 {
    # sites9 uses a contract version of 201701 (whereas web8 will use 201501)
    return (Get-CoreServiceContractVersion) -eq "201701"
} 

function Get-CoreServiceContractVersion 
{
    Write-Verbose "Determining latest contract version supported by Core Service ..."

    foreach($v in "201701", "201501")
    {
        if(Test-Url $cmsUrl "/webservices/CoreService$v.svc?wsdl")
        {        
            Write-Verbose "Core Service supports contract version $v"
            return $v
        }       
    }

    throw "Unable to determine Core Service version using base URL '$cmsUrl'"
}
```

At least. I did a test today from this [SDL.DXA.NET.2.2.9.zip](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/releases/download/DXA_2.2.9_Hotfix/SDL.DXA.NET.2.2.9.zip) in Tridion Sites 9.5 and confirm it was working fine, but didn't have a chance to test against in 8.5.

This is the command I did use in my environment which is HTTPS enabled.

```
.\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl https://localhost/ -cmsUserName username -cmsUserPassword xxxxx -cmsAuth Basic
```

Comment: Thanks, Velmurugan